# TypeError: request() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a script in Python3.6  that, among other things, obtains links from a site.xml. I failed to use `urllib3` That has been explained by the help of the community. Currently, I am stuck over this error. Going over the documentation at [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) I tried following examples but failed.

```
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager(10)
url = 'https://www.desertessence.com/sitemap.xml'

pagedata = http.request(url).data
```

Error is over missing argument `url`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/user/Downloads/1.py", line 6, in <module>
    pagedata = http.request(url).data
TypeError: request() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'
[Finished in 0.7s with exit code 1]
```

Answer (score 5):

[From the urllib3 docs](http://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.2.1/managers.html#urllib3.poolmanager.PoolManager.request) you were missing the `method` argument:

```
pagedata = http.request('GET', url).data
```

You were looking at the wrong request documentation.

Comment: Thank you fine sir

Answer (score 1):

you need to put http method try this

```
pagedata = http.request('GET', url).data
```

Answer (score 0):

i had to same promlem. i solved it this way :

```
managment=urllib3.PoolManager(10)
resp = managment.request('GET','url')
print(resp.data)
```